# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Selectize plugin is not loading in the localhost. It shows error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function

But it is working fine in the test server. No error is showing. It loads fine. 
The strange this is this worked on my localhost yesterday. I have not made any changes and when I opened the site today on localhost it shows this error.

Comment: So, how do you expect us to help, when we know nothing of your server / local host? (File structure, code)...

Comment: Check if the plugin is loaded correctly, and after jquery

Comment: What is your actual code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the answer. I have repeatedly loaded the jquery which made this error. When i removed the repetition it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check, does your jquery files coming from live server path or from local?

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function

This error only comes when your related jquery library is not placed in correct path.

Comment: Incorrect path, not loaded at all, loaded before jQuery is loaded... An incorrect path is merely one of the possible problems.